# Does my web service have to implement WCF in order for type reuse to work?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, asmx, webservice-client

I know that when creating WCF services and clients we can reuse the contract classes by using the [DataContract] attibute. Is there any way to do that when my web service is a legacy asmx web service?

When answering please consider that the only limitation I pose is on the service, the client proxy can be regenerated as a WCF client if that helps.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no-one responded and since I could find no evidence to the contrary in the months since I asked the question, I'm answering it myself:

No, type reuse between client and server is not possible when the service is implemented as an asmx web service.

If anyone knows otherwise please do share.

Comment: You've got it: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks @JohnSaunders for pointing that out. I am aware of that, the question was meant for supporting legacy code.